# How to use regex to find anything between two values?

Tags: python, regex

I have a survey printout extracted from a PDF with questions and answers written in this format:

"15. I feel confident in social situations. (Sometimes) 16. I feel lonely. (Often) 17. I feel energetic. (Never)"

I don't have code of my own because I don't really know where to begin.

What I want is a regex that will return the question between the number and the paranthesized response. For ex, I want just:

"I feel confident in social situations.", "I feel lonly.", "I feel energetic."

Comment: Generally it's more well received to try something before posting, but [here's](https://regex101.com/r/AQgKuv/1) a starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex with `g` flag:

```
(?<!\()\b[a-zA-Z ]+\b\.(?![\)])
```

**Regex Visualization:**

[image]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/rLaqko_Hl5FK3gCV)

**Explanation for each Regex element:**

`(?<!\()` - Negative Lookbehind

`\b` - assert position at a word boundary

`[a-zA-Z ]+` - Match a single character present in the list once or unlimited times

`\b` - assert position at a word boundary

`\.` - matches the character `.` literally

`(?![\)])` - Negative Lookahead

`g` flag - don't return after first match

**Match Result**:

> I feel confident in social situations.
>
> I feel lonely.
>
> I feel energetic.

Comment: (?<=\d+\.\s).+?\. another solution

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using regex, using `.split('.')` might work better for you here. This is assuming that the information you have is in a string format. If not, try to include more information about the extracted data.

You can see how to use the `split()` method [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)

Good luck!